# If $P(A_n) \ge \epsilon>0$ for large $n$, then $P(A_n i.o.) \ge \epsilon$

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

If $P(A_n) \ge \epsilon>0$ for large $n$, then $P(A_n i.o.) \ge \epsilon$.

I tried mimicking the proof of B-C but it give the wrong inequity in a different direction.

Comment: What is the definition of $[A_n$ i.o.$]$ in terms of unions and intersections, already?

Comment: its $\cap \cup A_n$

Comment: Not very precise--but what can you say about the probability of the unions in the formula?

Comment: $P(\cup A_n) \le \sum P(A_n)$. Is this what you mean?

Comment: No, you should be more interested in a *lower* bound of P(∪An).

Comment: I see, then $P(A_n) \le P(\cup A_n)$ for any $n$.

Comment: Yes, once you will have taken care of the indices, you will get something like P(∪An)≥P(Am)hence P(∪An)≥...

Comment: But how do I go from $P(\cap \cup A_n)$ to $P( \cup A_n)$??

Comment: This is the step where having been careless with the indices will begin to hurt...

Comment: Can you help me with this step. It seems to me that $P(\cap_{i=1}^\infty \cup_{j=i}^\infty A_j) \ge P( \cup_{j=i}^\infty A_j)$ does not hold. So how do I get this bound?

Comment: hey, what about this? $P(A_n i.o.)=P(\lim_{n \to \infty} \cup_{i=m}^\infty A_i) = \lim_{n \to \infty}P( \cup_{i=m}^\infty A_i) \ge  \epsilon$.

Comment: Are you able to complete the proof in the answer you accepted?

Comment: yes. Thanks for your help

Comment: Odd. Somehow this does not fit with your previous comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $B_N = \bigcup_{n \ge N} A_n$.  Then
$A_n \ \text{i.o.} = \bigcap_{N=1}^\infty B_N$.  Note that $B_{N+1} \subseteq B_N$.
Then countable additivity implies $P(\bigcap_{N=1}^\infty B_N) = \lim_{N \to \infty} P(B_N)$.